# Script for DB Backup that runs every day

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-backups

I have SQL Server Management Studio 2012 installed on a VM. We have an active DB (attached to an ASP.Net application whose target Framework is 4.0). What I was looking for is a **script to backup a DB** that I can attach to Task Scheduler to take backup once a day and copy that backup file to my local machine.

As far as copying of file is concerned I can do that using Robocopy, but I am yet to create a script to automatically take backup. I read a few articles but they were too outdated (SQL Server 2000).

Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: You mentioned SSMS is the 2012 version. Can you clarify what version of SQL Server you are using? Additionally can you clarify how you want to run the script? Is it okay to use SQL Server maintenance plans or to use PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/930615 to daily backup in `mssql server`

Comment: Step 8 in the link provided, "Script Action to Job" is disabled

Comment: No. I don't have SQL Express installed on my machine